# array delete itself the first 3 char in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have this data struct:

```
struct WordCounter
{
  char *word;
  int word_count;
  struct WordCounter *pNext;                        /* Pointer to the next word counter in the list */
};
```

I need it to memorize the words read from a file and how many times they occur. This struct has got these functions:

```
int giveCounter (struct WordCounter *pCounter){   // give the occurrence of the current word in the linked list
    int tempcount = pCounter -> word_count;
   return tempcount;
    
}

int lengthOfCurrentWord(struct WordCounter *pWordCounter) // length of the current string
{
    
    return strlen(pWordCounter->word)+1;  // for the null terminator string 
}

char* giveWord(struct WordCounter *pWordcounter){  // return current word of the linked list
    return pWordcounter->word;
}
```

What I should do, is to take all the words in the list and put them into an array that can hold them all where each word is separated by a terminator.
The code is this and after i explain where is the problem:

```
pCounter = pStart; // go to the first element in the linked list
num_car=0;  // in total how much character in all words
while(pCounter != NULL){
    num_car += lengthOfCurrentWord(pCounter);
    pCounter = pCounter -> pNext;
}
printf("total number of chars in all words is: %d \n ", num_car);
```

Ok now we have the dimension of the big array that have to save all words separated by a terminator.

```
char *exactly_word; // im forced to initialize like this and after i can  give the exactly number of elements
exactly_word = malloc(sizeof(char)*num_car); // The big array
memset(exactly_word,0,num_car);
```

Let's start to copy the word in the linked list into the big array:

```
char wordy[100] = {0}; // an array for the temp word
pCounter = pStart;  // go to the first element
int indice = 0;   // used for loop through single word
int indice_parole = 0;  // It is used to indicate in which position of the large array to insert the character
for(int x=0; x<readed_nd_word;x++){   // readed_nd_words is the number of element in the linked list
    
    strcat(wordy,giveWord(pCounter));  // copy the current word into wordy array
    printf("WORDY: %s \n",wordy);      // yeah correct in each iteration
   
    while(wordy[indice]!= 0){
        printf("Character to add to exactly word: %c, at position: %d \n",wordy[indice],indice_parole);
        exactly_word[indice_parole] = wordy[indice]; // copy character
        indice_parole++;
        indice++;
    }
    

    pCounter = pCounter -> pNext; // move into next word in the linked list
    memset(wordy,0,100);   // reset for a new word
    indice = 0;
    
    exactly_word[indice_parole] =0; // terminator for separating words
    printf("Terminator at position %d",indice_parole);
    indice_parole++; 
    
    
}
```

Where is the problem? ok in the while loop exactly_word is filled in the right way, but after this code if i try to print exactly_word[0] the output is:"", same for the position 1,2 of exactly_word. I can explain the problem better with an example, that i describe with the output:

```
words in the linked list:
  wut   1
  sut   1
  ov   1
  word   2
  ciao   1
  helo   1
  cor   1
  fal   1
  vermalen   1

total number of chars in all words is: 43 (countered the terminator too)
WORDY: wut 
Character to add to exactly word: w, at position: 0
Character to add to exactly word: u, at position: 1
Character to add to exactly word: t, at position: 2
terminator at position 3

WORDY: sut 
Character to add to exactly word: s, at position: 4
Character to add to exactly word: u, at position: 5 
Character to add to exactly word: t, at position: 6 
terminator at position 7
```

For the rest of the words the output is correct, but after this code as i said if i print exactly_word[0] i got a "", same as 1,2, instead at exactly_word[4] = "s" from the word sut.
If i print all the array i have got this: "sutovwordciaohelocorfalvermalen".

P.s. the bug doesn't show up at every run, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't, when it doesn't show up exactly word is corrected. There is something like undefiend behaivor that i can't see? please help :(

Comment: As a general comment (though not the cause of errors), `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition (the sizes are in units of characters), so multiplying it is unnecessary. (If you wish to make the type clear, IMO it is better to use the pattern `str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * len)`)

Comment: @Arkku yeah i see there is an error with the position, but why the first 3 char is missing? And why the behaivour is strange?

Comment: ASIDE: You could change `strcat(wordy,giveWord(pCounter));` to `strcpy(wordy,giveWord(pCounter));`. Then `char wordy[100] = {0};` could be changed to `char wordy[100];` and `memset(wordy,0,100);` can be removed.

Comment: @IanAbbott this is the error?

Comment: Instead of printing the array as text, try printing it each character as, e.g., hexadecimal, such as with `printf(" %02x", exactly_word[index])`. It could be that some control character is messing with your terminal.

Comment: @Arkku where i should insert this printf?

Comment: @Arkku i get this one: 01 00 00 00 73 75 74 00 6f 76 00 77 6f 72 64 00 63 69 61 6f 00 68 65 6c 6f 00 63 6f 72 00 66 61 6c 00 76 65 72 6d 61 6c 65 6e 00. the code is a loop from 0 to num_car

Comment: The range from 0x61 to 0x7A are the lowercase characters and the 0x00 between them are the terminators, but in the beginning you have somehow a 0x01 and three consecutive 0x00. I don't see how the code shown can cause this, so the problem is probably in the parts you didn't show, e.g., some variable overflows into the array.

Comment: OT: Your code is much much more complicated than needed. Why do you use `wordy`? Just place words directly into `exactly_word`

Comment: OT: Maybe read about `calloc`

Comment: OT: Why `strcat` when we have `strcpy` ?

Comment: "If i print all the array i have got this: "sutovwordciaohelocorfalvermalen"." How do you print it?

Comment: @4386427         for(int w = 0; w <num_car; w++){
            printf(" %c", exactly_word[w]); 
        }

Comment: OT: `for(int x=0; x<readed_nd_word;x++){` Why? with a linked list it normal to do `while(pCounter != NULL)`

Comment: Okay... at least that explains why the printing doesn't stop at the first `00`

Comment: It is obvious that you have a memory overwrite. Some code is storing the integer value 1 at the start of your `exactly_word`. But it is **not** any of the code you have posted....

Comment: Try this: 1) Change the first word to be longer - like "abcdefg" 2) Dump the first 16 elements of `exactly_word` (i.e. `printf(" %02x", exactly_word[index])`) **just after** the loop and **important** show us the code **including** the code for dumping the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you show us a hex dump of `exactly_word` to be

```
 01 00 00 00 73 75 74 00 6f 76 00 77 6f 72 64 ...
```

this indicates that you have a memory overwrite of the first 3 (maybe 4) bytes of `exactly_word`. Looks like the integer value `1` has been written to the start of the array (little endian) but that's just a guess because: **It doesn't happen in the code posted. It must be in code you didn't show us.**

That said, your current code is way to complex. Simplify it like:

```
exactly_word = malloc(num_car);
char* dst = exactly_word;
pCounter = pStart;
while(pCounter){
    strcpy(dst, giveWord(pCounter));
    dst += lengthOfCurrentWord(pCounter);  // which includes termination char
    pCounter = pCounter -> pNext;
}
```

Comment: Befor the code posted, i never use exactly word so his use start form the code posted, after this i just print exactly word, and it is where the magic happens, I have a lot of code excluding this, but is possible that the previous code affect the code in question?

Comment: I missed something, my exactly word is declared like this: char *exactly_word; is that a problem? Im forced to initialize in this way beacuse, im programming in mpi and the second processor (slave) can't know how much is the dimension of exactly_word at start. So i give dimension in the part of code, when i have num_car, but for other things i need that is declared before and filled after
@4386427

Comment: @GabrielePisapia I can't debug code that you don't show me!!! The code posted works fine. See https://ideone.com/QmvugI So I can only repeat: Your bug is in code that isn't posted

Comment: @GabrielePisapia Now you are mentioning **mpi**. I don't know much about that but AFAIK it's some multi-threading environment - isn't it? Could be a likely source of your bug, In any case: **your posted code is working fine**